Why does a center manifold appear when a potential flow is perturbed by a constant vector field?
Let $h(\mathbf{x})$ be a solution to the Laplace equation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ under some set of boundary conditions. Define $\mathbf{q}(\mathbf{x}) = -\nabla h(\mathbf{x})$. Let $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{q} + \boldsymbol{\zeta}$, where $\boldsymbol{\zeta}$ is a constant vector field.
In some numerical simulations of this scenario, we observe that $\mathbf{w}$ appears to contain a center manifold. This manifold separates the domain into two distinct regions.

Is the appearance of this center manifold significant from a mathematical perspective? It has a specific meaning in our application, but I am wondering if there is anything more general that can be said about it.
Does it only appear under certain circumstances? There are certainly cases where it does not (e.g., when $\mathbf{q}$ is already a constant vector field), but I would struggle to articulate exactly what the most general conditions for its existence are.
Is there a clever way of locating it computationally? At the moment, we are running particle tracking through $\mathbf{w}$ and examining the convex hull of the particle paths. This feels ‘brute force,’ and I am wondering if there is a more efficient, accurate, or faster method.


Too long for a comment, but here are some thoughts.
Denote the vector field driving the dynamical system by $f(x;\xi) = \nabla h(x) + \xi$, with Jacobian $J(x) = \nabla^2 h(x)$, the Hessian matrix of $h$.

Not sure if anything can be said in general, but the appearance of a center manifold can indicate the presence of various bifurcations.

The center manifold is the union of some trajectories extending from equilibrium points that are neither exponentially approaching or leaving the equilibrium points. By linearizing about the equilibrium, this tells us that at an equilibrium $x^*$, $J(x^*)$ must be singular. Furthermore, it can be shown that the center manifold is tangent to the null space of $J(x^*)$ at $x^*$. This gives us the following conditions for detecting a center manifold:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla h(x) + \xi &=0 \\
J(x)v&=0 \\
\|v\|^2-1&=0.
\end{aligned}
$$
Obviously this system will not have a solution for every $\xi$. There may be no solutions to the first equation, or the Jacobian (Hessian of $h$) may be nonsingular at any equilibrium points.

This nonlinear system is triangular, so we can proceed by finding all equilibria $x^*$ satisfying $\nabla h (x^*)-\xi=0$, then computing the null spaces of $J(x)$ at each $x^*$. The null eigenvectors of $J(x^*)$ are tangent to the center manifold, so they can be used as directions for numerical continuation. I am not familiar with current research on the topic, but a cursory search seems to indicate there is a decent amount of literature on the topic of approximating invariant manifolds. I know there is some work by Friedman in the 90s using numerical continuation and a shooting method but I am not sure how applicable that is to the general structure of the center manifold in this case. I also suspect that leveraging more knowledge of harmonic functions can help the analysis as well. For example, since $J(x)$ is the Hessian of a harmonic function, it is symmetric and trace zero so we know that the center manifold about $x^*$ must be locally two-dimensional in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and locally one or three-dimensional in $\mathbb{R}^3$.


